# Should I almost always use virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I see from [Virtual inheritance doesn't break static composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335288/5740428) that virtual inheritance adds `sizeof(pointer)` to an object's memory footprint. Other than that, are there any drawbacks to me just using virtual inheritance by default, and conventional inheritance only when needed? It seems like it'd lead to more future-proof class design, but maybe I'm missing some pitfall.

Comment: The order of initialization of base classes becomes non obvious to most people. Thus maintenance cost increase.

Comment: Virtual inheritance adds an internal pointer only on some implementations. Itanium ABI doesn't use internal pointers, only vptr.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The drawbacks are that

1. All classes will have to initialize all its virtual bases all the time (e.g. if A is virtual base of B, and C derives from B, it also have to initialize A itself).
2. You have to use more expensive `dynamic_cast` everywhere you use a `static_cast` (may or may not be the issue, depending on your system and whether your design requires it).

Point 1 alone makes it not worth it, since you can't hide your virtual bases. There is almost always a better way.

Comment: Oh god (1) is horrible. Thanks! Could you be more explicit about (2)? Do you mean that the compiler throws an error if I try to use static_cast<Derived*>(my_virtual_base_instance)?

Comment: @SuperElectric: why is (1) horrible? Would it be better if a base subobject were not initialised? ;)

Comment: Comments like "it's not worth it" show a complete failure to understand the purpose of virtual bases: virtual inheritance must *always* be used when you're subclassing an abstraction. There is no workaround or other possibility, if you fail to use it you cannot use multiple subclassing of abstractions without going back and fixing your design error, thus breaking encapsulation.

Comment: @Yttril: Perhaps Alex is merely suggesting that it's "not worth it" to do diamond inheritance of classes with data, something which Greg's answer suggests is almost always avoidable. I may be missing something, though, and I freely admit to "a complete failure to understand" what you're on about! (Thank goodness I'm teaching myself lisp; I think c++ can do something to one's personality after a while.)

Comment: @Yttrill @SuperElectric By "it's not worth it" I meant getting yourself into a situation where you'd need multiple virtual inheritance. By this point your design is too complex. As for point (2), it won't compile with `static_cast`.

Comment: @AlexB Nonsense; virtual inheritance isn't complex, it is very natural.

Comment: @AlexB I don't understand (1). All classes don't initialize all its base all the time (non virtual base) ?

Comment: @AlexB Ok, this means that C constructor has to explicitly initialize A (not only B).

Comment: @AlexB @Pedro Would you mind elaborating on why "you can't hide your virtual bases"? In [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c/) example, though not being efficient, I think the `TA` does not know the existence of `Person`, thus follows the principle of encapsulation?

Answer (score 15):

In my experience, virtual inheritance (as opposed to *virtual methods*) is almost never needed. In C++ it's used to address the ["diamond inheritance problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem), which if you avoid multiple inheritance cannot actually happen.

I'm pretty sure that I've never encountered virtual inheritance outside C++ books, which includes both code I write and million+ line systems I maintain.

Comment: The standard C++ I/O streams library uses virtual inheritance.  But yeah, other than that it's generally pretty rare.

Comment: Greg: +1 excellent generalization on the whole virtual inheritence mess.

Comment: Hmm... I already know what it's for (I'm thinking of using it), and I understand that it's rare (I code in c++), but the question posed was "what are the drawbacks of virtual inheritance".

Comment: Another possible answer is that virtual inheritance makes your code harder to read. For those people who don't regularly encounter virtual inheritance, they will have to learn about it and apply the extra cognitive load of remembering what it means whenever they read your code. For those who *do* understand it, they will wonder why you are using an unnecessary feature if none of your classes actually use diamond inheritance. The [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it) principle applies in this case.