# Diamond (multiple inheritance) with no data members

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Suppose we have the usual diamond-pattern:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual char foo() = 0;

    virtual ~A() {} 
};

class B :  public A
{
public:
    virtual char foo() { return 'B';}

    virtual ~B() {}
};

class C :  public A
{
public:
    virtual char foo() { return 'C';}

    virtual ~C() {}
};

class D :  public B,  public C
{
public:

    virtual char foo() { return 'D';}

    virtual ~D() {}
};
```

Please note that the base class `A` does not have any data members. It's in fact just an interface with pure virtual methods.

Now if i do:

```
D* d = new D();

A* a = static_cast<A*>(d);
```

the compiler will tell me that the cast is ambiguous as there are two A base classes.

But what if i do:

```
D* d = new D();

B* b = static_cast<B*>(d); // Or C* c = static_cast<C*>(d); 

A* a = static_cast<A*>(b);
```

Now i have a pointer to one of my `A` base classes and i can do `a->foo()`.

Is this safe?

What i want to know is if i can do this double-upcasting to just have pointer to interfaces (with no data members) without the overhead of virtual inheritance. I don't plan to downcast the pointer anyway or do anything with it that isn't calling virtual methods.

I know this means having two base classes but as there are no members it shouldn't matter, or does it?

`EDIT`:
I'm struggling to find a way to implement interfaces and i think i'll just have to use virtual inheritance.

Suppose i have a class `Buffer` (interface class), and a `BufferImplementation` class that derives from it.

Now suppose i have another interface `IOBuffer` (which derives from the other interface `Buffer`), with a `IOBufferImplementation` class that must derive both from `BufferImplementation` and the `IOBuffer` interface.

In my previous example, Buffer is A, BufferImplementation is B, IOBuffer is C, and IOBufferImplementation is D.

Comment: This isn't a diamond, since there's no virtual inheritance. Hence the ambiguity.

Comment: As @MikeSeymour already says this isn't diamond pattern. There is no problem other than (1) the ambiguity and (2) that comparing interface pointers does not reliably establish *object identity* (you can have at least two different interface pointers to same object).

Comment: in addition to the previous 2 posts, could it be that you have a design problem? Multiple inheritance is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @RichardHodges It could be a flaw in my design, however i'm struggling in finding a good way to implement interfaces. I'll edit my question.

Comment: If you have an issue with the diamond pattern (--independently whether it is really such one), why don't routinely use virtual inheritance? `class B :  public virtual A`, and the same for `C`. There aren't that many disadvantages, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543537/in-c-should-i-almost-always-use-virtual-inheritance).

Comment: @davidhight It's a performance-critical application. I did some tests and there's a slight slowdown when using virtual inheritance (due to pointer indirection). However i'll use it if that's the only choice.

Comment: If it is performance-critical, I would consider rewriting it in generic-programming style, e.g. by using CRTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Is this safe?
```

I think so. You are using one of the two paths to reach from the derived class `D` to Base `A`. You can now use the **Interface Members** safely.

Just one note, if there are *pure virtual methods* in `A` that is not `overridden` in `D`, then using `D->B->A` path will always call the `overridden` method in `B` (similar for `D->C->A` path), though the implementation in `C` was intended/useful.  This will also work when `A` has data members, and in this particular setup, the data members inherited via `D->B->A` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is NOT the diamond pattern!

If you want to make this to the diamond pattern, you have to `virtual inherit`!

```
class B :  virtual public A
```

and

```
class C :  virtual public A
```

Your version simply derives linear from the base classes which makes D containing two times the base class A. As a result the compiler has no chance to know which A should be selected if you ask for it. If you derive with virtual, you get only one A in D.

Remember, that you must call the constructor of A in D manually. Also if the constructor of C or D calls constructor of A! This call will not happen, if you create an instance of D!

Comment: What he has written IS the diamond "pattern", although it's not a design pattern but a "oh crap how did I end up here?" sort of anti-pattern.  What you're describing is a *solution* to the problems presented  of the diamond pattern - a solution only ever to be used if you absolutely *positively* can't refactor the diamond out!