# Effect of C++11 standard layout violation

Tags: c++, c++11, standard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t you use offsetof on non-POD strucutures in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129894/why-cant-you-use-offsetof-on-non-pod-strucutures-in-c)

I have two classes:

```
struct A{
  double one;
  float two;
};

struct B : public A{
  float three;
};
```

If I interpretete the C++11 standard layout restrictions correctly, then B is not standard
layout, because both B and A have non-static data members. I would like to use a construct
like B in combination with HDF5, which requires the use of the **offsetof** macro, which (to my knowledge) is restricted to standard-layout objects. My question is, what could go wrong, with an expression like

```
offsetof(B, three)
```

It works fine with gcc-4.6, but has anybody ever encountered unexpected behaviour in a similar situation? If so, which one and with which compiler? What is the worst case scenario?

Regards
Claas

Comment: I have read this one too, but the examples of offsetof failures all contain constructs which are much more difficult than the example above. That's why I am curious about the chances of the example above to show unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The standard says directly (§18.2/4): "*If type is not a standard-layout class, the results are undefined.*" You really want a definition for "undefined"?

Comment: No, I was actually not looking for a definition of "undefined". I completely agree, that the code above is not backed by the standard and thus should not be used. Out of curiosity, however, I was wondering, whether there exists at least one implementation of the standard, which causes the above example to fail. So it was more a practical than theoretical question.