# Taking offset of a reference member (non PODs)

Tags: c++, templates, offset

Here is the code snippet

```
#include <iostream>
struct Z
{
   Z():x(0),y(0),z(x){}
   ~Z(){}

   int x;
   int y;
   int &z; // Reference member
};
template <typename Type, typename C, typename M>
size_t Offsetof (M C::* ptr_to_member)
{
  Type type;
  return reinterpret_cast<char*> (&(type.*ptr_to_member)) - reinterpret_cast<char*> (&type);
}
int main()
{
   std::cout << Offsetof<Z>(&Z::x); // works
   std::cout << Offsetof<Z>(&Z::y); // works 
   std::cout << Offsetof<Z>(&Z::z); // doesn't work
}
```

We cannot create pointer to reference so the function `Offsetof` won't work for `z`.

Is there any way to take offset of a reference data member for non PODs?

Comment: Might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129894/why-cant-you-use-offsetof-on-non-pod-strucutures-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. References are not objects, and they do not exist or have addresses or offsets. A pointer to a member reference is illegal.

Comment: Whether a reference takes memory is unspecified. On most implementations a reference is implemented as a const pointer right? There should be some implementation specific way to do the same which I am not aware of.

Comment: Why? The implementation of a reference is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no guarantee it has an offset, and even if it has an offset, it is not required to be the same for every instance of objects of this type (the compiler can use lookup tables). Sorry, that's just the way C++ is.