# Accessing Members of Outer Class without Storing Pointer

Tags: c++, oop

**PROBLEM:**

I want to set up a system of elements, while at the same time keeping **pairs** of these elements that I want to **access** and **modify** easily *(add more)*.

At the same time, I want to **keep the complexity to a minimum**, and not implement everything in one class.

I decided to store the indices to the pairs using a struct, which can handle a large amount of the complexity of calculations among B's.

```
class A {
    class B_pair {
        int idx_of_B[2];

    public:
        B get_B_value_1(); // how to access B's?
        B get_B_value_2();
        // a lot more member functions
    };

public:
    std::vector<B>  B_values;
    std::vector<B_pair>  special_B_pairs;
    // a lot more stuff
};
```

However, I have the problem that I cannot access the B values from within the B_pair class.

**FAILED SOLUTION 1**

```
class A {
    A() { B_pair::outer = this; }
    class B_pair {
        static A *outer;
        void init_outer(A *o);
    };
}
```

I used a `static` member because I have a lot of `B_pair` objects, and the **extra memory of a pointer/reference in each is significant**.

This works fine. However, if I have more than one A objects at the same time, then it is problematic, as the `outer` pointer ends up pointing at the last created `A` object.

**FAILED SOLUTION 2**

Another approach I took was storing **pointers**.

```
class A {
    class B_pair {
        B *items[2];
    };
    std::list<B>  B_values; // I need random access iterators!!
};
```

However, this means that I need to use more inefficient data structures than `std::vector`, which invalidates its iterators when it expands.

**QUESTION**

How could I access the members of the outer `class A` from the inner `class B`, or something similar to make this work? Ideally, I would like something similar to the first solution, but with one instance of `A *outer` for each `A` object.

Note that [THIS IS POSSIBLE IN JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)!!

**P.S.** At the moment I am using the Singleton design pattern, and kept the static pointer. Not a big fan of this solution.

Comment: You need to store a regular pointer in each `B_pair` object. If these were POD classes you could use `offsetof` to get a pointer to `A` from `&B_values`, but that doesn't work for non-POD classes.

Comment: @Barmar I can't access `&B_values` though. My inner class only has an index to an element in `B_values`. Btw why would this not work for non-POD? Do member functions affect size in any way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129894/why-cant-you-use-offsetof-on-non-pod-structures-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: if you're asking for architectural direction, make `B` a "dumb" object that is managed by `A` where access and modification of `B`s is done through calls on an `A`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Sure, but this obfuscates code... `objectA.first(objectA.special_B_pairs[i])` instead of `objectA.special_B_pairs[i].first()` ?

Comment: It looks like `B_pair`s represent a link, you could, again, make it dumb and make it clear it only has `B` "indexes" that can be accessed through an `A` (i.e. `objectA.getB(objectA.special_B_pairs[i].first)`). That's how many graph-like structures are done.