# Accumulate result from member function of elements in a container

Tags: c++, stl, std, stl-algorithm

I have a class, with a function which returns a count, like this:

```
class CTestClass
{
public:
    // ...
    size_t GetCount()const;
    // ...
};
```

And somewhere in my program I have a vector of objects of that class. I have a function to get the total count (sum of results of CTestClass::GetCount()), implemented like a normal loop:

```
size_t sum = 0;
for(vector<CTestClass>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    sum += it->GetCount();
}
```

I want to refactor it to use the facilities available in the standard library, and I thought of `accumulate`. I've been able to do it by using a function object (easy), but I'm almost sure it can be done without declaring another object (I don't have C++11 or boost, so no lambdas, but I have TR1).
When looking for an answer, I've found these resources, but they don't solve the question:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204871/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-the-result-of-a-member-function-for-all-elements-in-a) is pretty much the same question, and the answers provided
  are a loop, accumulate and functor, and accumulate and lambda, but there's an unanswered reference to bind and the like.
- [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030634/385646) uses `accumulate`, `plus` and
  `bind`, but uses a data member instead of a member function.

So, is there a way to do this using bind, or something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;
using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;

accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0,
           bind(plus<size_t>(), _1, bind(&C::GetCount, _2))
);
```

Comment: I think it should be `std::tr1::placeholders`, because he has `tr1`. (I'm not sure, though).

Comment: @fschoenm: I've reformatted the code so the predicate stands out a bit more (and there is no need for horizontal scrolling). Feel free to revert if you find it ugly.

Comment: This is one of the things I've tried, adapting one of the references I mentioned in the question, but the compiler (VS2008) complains with: "error C2664: '_Ret std::tr1::_Callable_obj<_Ty,_Indirect>::_ApplyX<_Ret,_Barg0,unsigned int>(_Arg0 &,_Arg1 &) const' : no se puede convertir el parámetro 2 de 'unsigned int' a 'unsigned int &" which translates as "cannot convert parameter 2 from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned int&'

Comment: It seems like VS2008's implementation of bind is buggy. That's why I've had problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

This works, too:

```
class CTestClass
{
public:
    // ...
    size_t GetCount()const;
private:
    operator size_t() { return GetCount(); }
    // ...
    template <typename InputIterator, typename T>
    friend T std::accumulate(InputIterator, InputIterator, T);

};


std::vector<CTestClass> v;
// fill vector

size_t result = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

No TR1, no bind :)

Comment: +1 ...but: You usually *should not* add an otherwise meaningless conversion operator to a class. For example, if the class is `CUniversity`, and GetCount is `GetEnrollment`, then such an operator would mean that you can convert a university to an unsigned integer :)

Comment: @kol you've got a point. I updated the example, making it a bit safer.

Comment: Thanks for your original answer, but I was thinking of something more general and which does not require to change CTestClass. I mean, what if I cannot change it (i.e. it's part of an API, library, or anything)? Or what if I need to run accumulate on more than one member function of the class (e.g. sometimes on X() and sometimes on Y())?

Comment: @MikMik If the class belongs to an API then you're stuck with what it exposes to you and you're best off with using bind, I guess. The method you already know (using functors) is IMHO the cleanest, though. With functors, you can also easily control what you want to be included in `accumulate`.